# what am I missing in this simple jquery?

Tags: jquery

what am I missing here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('cat_image_table').on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Clearly something because it is not working.. Seems to be so simple yet so wrong..

http://jsfiddle.net/JKpev/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That'd be a `.` in your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.cat_image_table').on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: The best kind of answers to this kind of question are punctual :^)

Answer (score 0):

you should put either # if you use ID selector or . if you use class selector.